# I'm trying to get each Australian state to appear on Google Maps, but only 3 are. Is it a size issue with the KML files?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, kml

I'm hoping somebody can help me with this. I can get the electorate data for NT, SA and ACT showing on Google Maps by linking to the KML files I have uploaded to Google Sites, but the states with larger files aren't displaying. I though that using this script would overcome the size issue. Here's the code with the links:

```
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 11,
      center: {lat: -35.2809, lng: 149.1300}
    });

    var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
      url: 'http://sites.google.com/site/kmltestsitey/kml-page/ACT.kml',
      map: map
    });

    var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
      url: 'http://sites.google.com/site/kmltestsitey/kml-page/NT.kml',
      map: map
    });

    var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
      url: 'http://sites.google.com/site/kmltestsitey/kml-page/SA.kml',
      map: map
    });

    var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
      url: 'http://sites.google.com/site/kmltestsitey/kml-page/TAS.kmz',
      map: map
    });

    var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
      url: 'http://sites.google.com/site/kmltestsitey/kml-page/VIC.kml',
      map: map
    });

    var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
      url: 'http://sites.google.com/site/kmltestsitey/kml-page/WA.kml',
      map: map
    });

    var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
      url: 'http://sites.google.com/site/kmltestsitey/kml-page/NSW.kml',
      map: map
    });
}
```

If it is a size issue, is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Related question:

- [google map api (KML layer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33056005/google-map-api-kml-layer)

If you check the KmlStatus of the layers, you will see:

- status ACT=OK
- status NT=OK
- status SA=OK
- status WA=INVALID_DOCUMENT
- status TAS=INVALID_DOCUMENT (**looks like this is not a kmz file, it is a .kml file renamed .kmz**)
- status VIC=INVALID_DOCUMENT (**this file contains invalid coordinates, `<coordinates>-167.827099999879,2407515.604 -5.93339999997988,2407479.8227`, the second coordinate, latitude, must be between +90 and -90, it is way larger than that, possibly a failed coordinate transform**)
- status NSW=INVALID_DOCUMENT

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer#restrictions):

> **Maximum fetched file size (raw KML, raw GeoRSS, or compressed KMZ)**
>   
> 3MB
>   
> **Maximum uncompressed KML file size**
>   
> 10MB
>   
> **Maximum number of network Links**
>   
> 10
>   
> **Maximum number of total document-wide features**
>   
> 1,000
>   
> **Number of KML layers**
>   
> There is a limit on the number of KML Layers that can be displayed on a single Google Map. If you exceed this limit, none of your layers will appear on the map, and an error will be reported in your web browser's JavaScript console. The limit is based on a combination of the number of KMLLayer classes created and the total length of all the URLs used to create those layers. Each new KMLLayer you create will take up a portion of the limit for the layer and a further portion of the limit depending on the length of the URL where the KML file was loaded from. Consequently, the number of layers you can add will vary by application; on average, you should be able to load between 10 and 20 layers without hitting the limit. If you still hit the limit, use a URL shortner (such as https://goo.gl) to shorten the KML URLs. Alternatively, create a single KML file consisting of NetworkLinks to the individual KML URLs.

**file sizes**

- 6,503,418 TAS.kmz (**too big, bigger than 3MB**)
- 8,353,172 VIC.kml (**too big, bigger than 3MB**)
- 5,994,333 WA.kml  (**too big, bigger than 3MB**)
- 13,325,408 NSW.kml (**too big, bigger than 3MB**)
- 195,125 ACT.kml
- 1,820,578 NT.kml
- 2,654,105 SA.kml

As a workaround, you could try compressing VIC.kml, WA.kml, and NSW.kml (to .kmz files) to see if that makes them smaller that 3MB.

- 3,540,878 NSW.kmz
- 1,512,043 WA.kmz
- 3,324,367 VIC.kmz

Which works for WA but not for VIC and NSW.  So you need to find a way to make the contents of TAS, VIC and NSW smaller, or use [FusionTablesLayer (this example uses the Natural Earth data set)](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test//v3_FusionTables_CountryBrowser_encryptedID.html?country=Australia) or a third party parser to display them.

[example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/mLy4vuL0/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 11,
    center: {
      lat: -35.2809,
      lng: 149.1300
    }
  });
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  var ctaLayerACT = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://sites.google.com/site/kmltestsitey/kml-page/ACT.kml',
    map: map,
    preserveViewport: true
  });
  checkStatus(ctaLayerACT, "ACT", bounds);

  var ctaLayerNT = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://sites.google.com/site/kmltestsitey/kml-page/NT.kml',
    map: map,
    preserveViewport: true
  });
  checkStatus(ctaLayerNT, "NT", bounds);

  var ctaLayerSA = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://sites.google.com/site/kmltestsitey/kml-page/SA.kml',
    map: map,
    preserveViewport: true
  });
  checkStatus(ctaLayerSA, "SA", bounds);

  var ctaLayerTAS = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://sites.google.com/site/kmltestsitey/kml-page/TAS.kmz',
    map: map,
    preserveViewport: true
  });
  checkStatus(ctaLayerTAS, "TAS", bounds);

  var ctaLayerVIC = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kmz/VIC.kmz',
    map: map,
    preserveViewport: true
  });
  checkStatus(ctaLayerVIC, "VIC", bounds);

  var ctaLayerWA = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kmz/WA.kmz',
    map: map,
    preserveViewport: true
  });
  checkStatus(ctaLayerWA, "WA", bounds);

  var ctaLayerNSW = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kmz/NSW.kmz',
    map: map,
    preserveViewport: true
  });
  checkStatus(ctaLayerNSW, "NSW", bounds);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);

var bndsRect;

function checkStatus(layer, idStr, bounds) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'status_changed', function() {
    console.log("status " + idStr + "=" + layer.getStatus());
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'defaultviewport_changed', function() {
    var rect = new google.maps.Rectangle({
      bounds: layer.getDefaultViewport(),
      fillOpacity: 0.2,
      strokeOpacity: 0.2,
      map: map
    });
    // if (bounds.isEmpty()) bounds = layer.getDefaultViewport();
    // else 
    bounds.union(layer.getDefaultViewport());
    console.log("bounds after " + idStr + "=" + bounds.toUrlValue())
    if (!bndsRect) {
      bndsRect = new google.maps.Rectangle({
        bounds: bounds,
        fillColor: "blue",
        fillOpacity: 0.2,
        strokeColor: "blue",
        strokeOpacity: 0.2,
        map: map
      });
      // map.fitBounds(bounds);
    } else {
      bndsRect.setBounds(bounds);
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance with this. That is very helpful. I'll try out reducing the file sizes and I'll have a go putting NSW into a fusion table. You're right that TAS was just a renamed kml file. I have made it into a proper KMZ using Google Earth. I think there's an issue with the co-ords in both the VIC and TAS files which I got from the AEC website. They have a national dataset there that might be better.

Comment: If this answered your question, please [accept it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)